# Setting up OrientDB server clusters on OpenShift

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, orientdb

I am trying to set up an OrientDB server cluster, where multiple pods have their own orientDB server, and they all contain the same data, no matter which pod's database you modify.

When I set this up locally, I can just start up multiple containers that run OrientDB's dserver.sh, and OrientDB's multicast ability allows the different containers/servers to find themselves. However when I'm running multiple instances on different pods they can't find themselves.

I'm currently thinking I'm supposed to have the pods on the same kubernetes service, and then they should be able to do the same? But I'm not making any headway.

How do I get multiple pods on OpenShift all to connect to each other, as if I was doing this with different containers on my local machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get multicast support in your cluster using [Weave](https://www.weave.works/use-cases/multicast-networking/) network solution.

> ### Summary
>
> With multicast, data can be distributed to multiple receivers that are in the same multicast group. It is used by
> applications that generate and distribute data feeds to other
> applications such as financial services.
>
> Weave Net fully emulates a layer 2 network, and operates just like a
> server that is attached to a standard Ethernet network. Multicast with
> Weave Net works even if the underlying network doesn’t support it,
> which is the case with Amazon Web Services (AWS), Azure, GCP and other
> public clouds.
>
> ### What it Does
>
> - Provides full multicast support for contained and uncontained applications
> - Works in data centers and public clouds, regardless of the underlying network
> - Uses industry-standard VXLAN and in-kernel switching for top performance
> - Automatic service discovery through DNS lookups